# Android Mobile Applications

Tags: android, sql-server, mobile

I would like to do a small application that connects to SQL server and brings data to a mobile device. Does anybody knows a good sample from A to Z for doing this?
Thank you.

Comment: This is not a good way to ask here, please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/about) first.

Comment: Boy oh boy! I just got in to give a vote down.

@rgx71 try some basics first.You should try for chat rooms instead of opening questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to connect your android app to the server you would need to make an HTTP request that will run your server side script (php for example), query a database and return a response to android device as a JSON object. Check this detailed tutorial:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

It shows an example of how to use android, php and mysql database.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I believe it should be the same concept using sql server right?

Comment: Right. Check the documentation how to connect php to SQL server. It's here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php